# Can't open text file in war folder, AccessControlException thrown?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a foo.txt file in my /war folder. I'm trying to open it using the File class, but get an exception:

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.io.FilePermission
  /foo.txt read)
  at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:374)
  at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:549)
  ...
```

From reading the docs on static/resource files, it seems like the text file should already be available. Does it need some extra setting to allow reading?:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig?hl=en#Static_Files_and_Resource_Files

I'm using the local dev server on a mac.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that if you are going to read data files in your Java code and need a place to put your data files (.txt or .csv), etc -- then do the following:

- Go to `WEB-INF` folder
- Create some folder inside of the `WEB-INF` folder. e.g. `WEB-INF\data`
- Place your files in the above folder. E.g. `sample.txt`
- In your Java IO code, you can then refer to the file via `WEB-INF\data\sample.txt`